# Rebuild Index in SQL Only On One Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Looking to create a SQL query that rebuilds indexes in SQL on only one table within my database. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Someone earlier suggested Ola Hallengren SQL maintenance, but I think that is too robust for what I'm after.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's a difference between REORGANIZE and REBUILD.  See [this blog post](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/index-maintenance-sql-server-rebuild-reorganize/) for details.

If you truly want to REBUILD, and you want to do it for ALL indexes on a given table, then the command would be (straight from the [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that [npe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1344008/npe) pointed you at):

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON mySchema.myTable REBUILD
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ALTER INDEX indexName ON mySchema.myTable REORGANIZE;
```

For more instructions [see the official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The link points to SQL Server 2014 docs, but the syntax should work on 2005 and 2008 as well.